# How to prove $\int_{\mathbb R} \nabla_u F (x, u_k(x))\cdot\varphi dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} \nabla_u F (x, u(x))\cdot\varphi dx$ for all test function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x, u)\in C^1(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$ and let $(u_k)$ be a sequence such that
$$ u_k\to u \text{ in } L^\infty_{loc}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^n)$$
and
$$ u_k\to u \text{ a.e. in } \mathbb R.$$

I want to use these information to get that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \nabla_u F (x, u_k(x))\cdot\varphi dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} \nabla_u F (x, u(x))\cdot\varphi dx \quad\forall \varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^n)$$
as $k\to +\infty$.

Anyone can please provide some hints?
I can not use Fatou's Lemma (since I don not know if the sequence is nonnegative) and I can not use the dominated convergence theorem (since I can not find a function of $L^1$ to dominate that quantity.
The only idea left is to observe that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \nabla_u F (x, u_k(x))\cdot\varphi dx = \int_{supp(\varphi)} \nabla_u F (x, u_k(x))\cdot\varphi dx,$$
but I am not sure how to use this information.

Anyone could please help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be the compact support of $\varphi$. Then we can write:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \nabla_u F(x, u_k(x))\cdot \varphi ~\mathrm{d}x = \int_K\nabla_u F(x, u_k(x))\cdot \varphi ~\mathrm{d}x
$$
Because of $u_k\rightarrow u $ in $L^\infty_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that $u_k \rightarrow u$ in $L^\infty(K)$. So $u_k \rightarrow u$ pointwise a.e. in $K$. Because of continuity, $\nabla_u F(x, u_k(x)) \rightarrow \nabla_u F(x, u(x))$ for a.e $x \in K$.

Then note that because of convergence, there is some $L>0$ such that $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lVert u_k - u \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} \leq L$ Then:
$$
\lVert u_k \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} \leq \lVert u_k - u \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} + \lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} \leq L +  \lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} 
$$
Set $r:= L +  \lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} $. Then for a.e. $x \in K$:
$$
\lvert \nabla_u F(x, u_k(x)) \varphi(x) \rvert \leq \lVert \varphi \rVert_{L^\infty(K)} \sup_{(x, y) \in K \times \overline{B_r(0)}} \lvert \nabla_u F(x, y)  \rvert
$$
The right hand side is finite uniformly in $k$, since $(x, y) \in K \times \overline{B_r(0)}$ is compact and the gradient is continuous.
So dominated convergence gives your result.

Comment: Meowdog, thank you for the answer. I agree that the RHS is finite, but then it is $L^1(K)$?

Comment: Yes ofc! Let $R$ be the constant on the RHS. Then $\int_K R \leq \lvert K \rvert R $. Due to compactness of $K$, this is finite